# Why is there a size difference in the executable file when i compile the code using gcc and eclipse cdt

Tags: c, gcc, eclipse-cdt

There is a difference of size in the executable file when i compile the code with gcc (using the terminal) and eclipse cdt.**gcc 8kb and eclispse 27 kb**.why does it happen? Isn't the eclipse using the same gcc compiler that was preinstalled?. The program is very simple ,but would it make significant size increment for larger code and compromize program performance ?

Comment: Depends on what optimizations and versions you're running. gcc 3 will produce different code from gcc 2, and the -O optimization levels will also heavily affect final sizes. You're comparing apples and elephants, basically, unless you can guarantee the same options were used in both compilation runs.

Comment: Try adding `-s` to the command line in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Eclipse is using the same `gcc`. However, it's likely that Eclipse add to the binary file some information for its debugging. For example, it's likely that Eclipse runs `gcc` with `-g` options which will include inside the binary the whole source code. This can result in very big difference about executable size.

For example, try to compile this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("Hello, world!");

    return 0;
}
```

Try  with:

```
$ gcc -o program program.c
$ gcc -o program_g program.c
$ ls -lh | grep program
-rwxr-xr-x  1 zagorax users     7,8K set 11 19:37 program
-rwxr-xr-x  1 zagorax users     8,4K set 11 19:37 program_g
-rw-r--r--  1 zagorax users      105 set 11 19:35 program.c
```

Of course, different `gcc` option may result in different size.

Comment: @MuhammadTaha,   
Actually, I don't know if it can affect program efficiency. I don't think so, to be honest, but someone could deny it. Unless you're running a program which is efficiency oriented (in which case you should investigate better) make your life easier with Eclipse or some other IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Eclipse CDT has two build configurations named "Debug" and "Release". By default it builds "Debug" that results in a bigger executable size due to less optimizations and inclusion of the debug information. You can reproduce this by passing gcc -O0 and -g flags.

It is likely that "Release" build will produce executable of the comparable size to what you get from the command line. Note that 'Release" build may yet pass some flags that alter executable size (e.g. it can enable deeper optimization).

You can find the command line flags CDT passes to GCC in build console view and in the generated make files.

Note, as name implies, "Debug" version of the executable is to be used for debugging and it should not be distributed to the users. As a rule, it may be noticeably slower and may provide some debug output that is not meant for user eyes. On the other hand, debugging "Release" build may be a tough endeavour as it may optimize out some code you would like to observe in debugger, reshuffle code lines and be unable to link source code to the program execution.